# Unable to recognize any objects in Chrome browser

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

Unable to recognize objects on Chrome browser via UFT 14.02

- I am using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 and UFT  14.02
- I have installed HPE Functional Testing Agent along with agent crx file item.
- The Chrome browser is zoomed to 100%.

Using Object Spy, I am unable to recognize any object in the entire page. Every time, I try to hover over or click, it shows me as:

> WinObject: Chrome Legacy Window

Also, If I try to click on record by going to "Record & Run settings → Open the following when recording or running".

I am getting the following error, though:

> Unable to Launch browser. The specified browser is not installed

Comment: Is HPE Functional Testing Agent add-on enabled in Chrome?

Comment: @PankajJaju Hi Pankaj, Yes! I have enabled it in the browser

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the following steps to solve my problem:

1. Set the system display settings to "100%" and resolution "2560 X 1440". Once this done, log out and log in back for the changes to take effect
2. Zoom the Chrome browser to "100%".
3. Drag and drop `Agent.crx` from the `Installation/Chrome` folder to browser to install the Extension.
4. Launch UFT and then launch Chrome browser. Use Object Spy, you can now see that objects are being identified.

Comment: I don't see where this "Agent.crx" file is.  Where is this located?

Comment: I guess, I am responding very late. Apologies for that. "Agent.crx" is located in the installation folder of UFT in your system. Just navigate to the UFT installation folder. It will probably be in C: or C:\users folder and then locate the Chrome folder. In there we have this file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. UFT had already installed the Agent Extension, but it was disabled. Enabled it from Extensions page.  Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Open chrome://flags.
- Search for "Touch events API" and set it to "Enabled"
- Search for "User Activation V2" and set it to "Enabled"
- Click the restart chrome prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Chrome is having the HPE Functional testing Agent through Options → MoreTools → Extensions.

And Enable if it is already installed and in Disable Mode